# Change Cell Color of Excel file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I googled a lot and tried many different codes to achieve this, but no sign of success this far. Here's my code:

```
Imports Excel= Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim style As Excel.Style = worksheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("NewStyle")

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        If Val(MeterCount.Text) >= Val(S1.Text) Then
            DC1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            DN1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            S1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            T1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
            worksheet.Cells(2, 1).Style = "NewStyle"
        Else
            DC1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            DN1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            S1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
            T1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above code returns with error : System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is this a cut down version of your full code? I would recommend you have specific methods for creating all the Excel objects and style.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Public Sub setColor()
 Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
 Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

 Dim stl As style

 Dim styleExists As Boolean
 styleExists = False

 For Each stl In wbk.Styles
     If stl.Name = "styleX" Then
         styleExists = True
     End If
 Next stl

 If styleExists = False Then
     With wbk.Styles.Add("styleX")
      .Interior.Color = vbYellow
     End With
 End If

 wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).style = "styleX"
End Sub
```

Comment: I get these errors with this code: (1) 'ActiveWorkbook' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. (2) Type 'style' not defined. (3) 'vbYellow' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: what Excel version you use?